# how to open a new window from a double click on an element of a list?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, toplevel

I have to realize a project which is to make an interface from a database. I code under python 3, my database is on sqlite and my graphical interface is obtained with tkinter. I have a list of elements (MP, PSI, PT ...) and I want to open a new window by double clicking on an element of this list.

I already managed to open a new window. However, this window opens automatically instead of opening when I double click on an item in the list.

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
bdd = sqlite3.connect("BDD.db")
curseur = bdd.cursor()


def fenetre_filiere():
    fenetre=Tk()
    fenetre.geometry("800x500")
    champ_label = Label(fenetre, text="Choisissez une filière")
    champ_label.pack()

filieres=liste_des_filieres()

liste_filieres = Listbox(fenetre)
liste_filieres.pack()


for i in range(len(filieres)):
    print(i,filieres[i])
    liste_filieres.insert(i,filieres[i])

liste_filieres.bind ('<Double-1>',open_fenetre()) ###Here is my problem###

def open_fenetre():
   fenetre2 = Tk()
   fenetre2.geometry("80x50")

def liste_des_filieres():
   req="""SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(NOMFILIERE)
   FROM FILIERE;"""
   curseur.execute(req)
   return curseur.fetchall()
```

I would like to be able to open a new window when I double click on an element of this list.

Answer (score 0):

After you have populated your `tk.Listbox`, you can `bind` a `double click` event to it, and have the event pop a `tk.Toplevel` window that shows what you need to display from the data:

You should usually not have more than one call to `tk.Tk()` per application.

maybe something like this simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def pop_window(dummy_event):
    data = listbox.get(listbox.curselection()[0])
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    tk.Label(top, text=f'popup window \nfor data: {data}').pack()


root = tk.Tk()
listbox = tk.Listbox(root)

# populating the listbox with random data
for _ in range(random.randint(1, 11)):
    listbox.insert(tk.END, random.randint(0, 1000))

listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", pop_window)
listbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```